# SPI Arduino communication

Tags: spi, c++

I want two Arduino cards to communicate with each other using SPI and move the servo motor with potentiometer as a result. I've done the pre-burning led or the led burning led on the SPI, I am waiting for your help. I will give the code below.

MASTER Arduino code

```
#include <SPI.h>
/* SPI haberleşmesinde Master olarak görev yapan Arduino kodu */
const int pot=A0;   // Servo kontrol potunu bağlayacağımız analog giriş.
int potdurum=0;     
int pos = 0;       
const int SSpini = 8;  
/* Slave görevindeki Arduino'nun seçilmesi için 8 bumaralı pin SS olarak belirlendi */

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(SSpini, OUTPUT);
  /* SS pini çıkış olarak ayarlandı */
  digitalWrite(SSpini, HIGH);
  /* Slave olan Arduino başlangıçta haberleşmeye geçmemesi için SS pini HIGH yapıldı */
  SPI.begin();
  /* SPI haberleşmesi başlatıldı */
}

void loop()
{
  potdurum=analogRead(pot);
  pos= map(potdurum,0,1023,0,180);//Pottan okunan değeri  180e oranlıyoruz.
  veriGonder(pos,SSpini);
}


/* SPI üzerinden veri göndermek için yazılmış fonksiyondur */
void veriGonder(int veri, int SSpini)
{
  digitalWrite(SSpini, LOW);
  /* Diğer Arduino'nun veri dinlemeye başlaması için SS hattını LOW düzeyine çekmeliyiz */
  delay(1);
  /* Kısa bir süre bekleyelim */
  Serial.print("Aci Degeri = ");
  Serial.println(veri);
  delay(15);
  SPI.transfer(veri);
  /* veri karakteri diğer Arduino'ya yollandı
  * Fonksiyon diğer arduino'dan gelen veriyi vermektedir
  * Geri gelen veri LEDDurumu değişkeninde tutulmuştur
  * Bu değişken Seri port üzerinden bilgisayardaki Serial monitöre yollanmıştır
  */
  digitalWrite(SSpini, HIGH);
  /* Haberleşmeyi bitirmek için pin LOW konumuna çekilmiştir */
}
```

SLAVE Arduino code

```
#include <Servo.h>
int i = 0;
Servo myservomotor;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myservomotor.attach(3);
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SS , INPUT);
  /* MISO pini OUTPUT, SS pini INPUT olarak ayarlandı */


  SPCR  |= 0b11000000;
  SPSR  |= 0b00000000;
  /* Slave mod ve interrupt için ayarlamalar yapıldı */ 

  sei();
  /* Interruptlar çalıştırıldı */
}  

void loop()
{
}

/* SPI kesmesi olduğunda çalışacak fonksiyon */
ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{
  cli();
  /* Interruptlar durdurulmuştur */
  while(!digitalRead(SS))
  {
      SPDR = i;
      i ++;
      if ( i > 255) 
        i = 0;
      while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
      /* SPI hattında veri aktarımı bitene kadar bekle */
      int gelenVeri;
      gelenVeri = SPDR;
      myservomotor.write(gelenVeri);
      Serial.print("Aci Degeri Slave= ");
      Serial.println(gelenVeri);
      delay(15);

//      if(gelenVeri == 'a'){
//        digitalWrite(SERVO,HIGH);
//      }else if(gelenVeri == 'b'){
//        digitalWrite(SERVO,LOW); 
//      }
      /* SPI üzerinden gelen verinin değerine göre LED'in konumu değiştirildi */
  }
  sei();
  /* Interruptlar başlatılmıştır */
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The basic error is too much code in the SPI ISR. Focus on capturing the SPI value and then flag to the loop() function that a new value is available. Avoid delay and serial print in ISRs.

Comment: @LookAlterno - this site requires posts and comments to be in English, thanks.

Comment: *I am waiting for your help.* - for what, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

```
/* SPI kesmesi olduğunda çalışacak fonksiyon */
ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{
  cli();
 ...    
      Serial.print("Aci Degeri Slave= ");
      Serial.println(gelenVeri);
```

Don't do serial prints inside an ISR.